# Trouble getting pandas to read entire column of data

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, text

The goal for this program to accomplish is to read each column header and to read all of the data underneath each column. After reading this data it will then make a list of it and log it all into a text file. When doing this with small data it works but when working with large amounts of data (2000 lines and up) it records in the text file up to the number 30 then the next element is '...'. it then resumes recording correctly all the way up until the 2000th element.

I have tried all that i can do. Plz help. I almost punched a hole in the wall trying to fix this.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import linecache
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def create_dict(df):
    # Creates an empty text file for the dictionary if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.isfile("Dictionary.txt"):
        open("Dictionary.txt", 'w').close()

    # Opens the dictionary for reading and writing
    with open("Dictionary.txt", 'r+') as dictionary:

        column_headers = list(df)

        i = 0
        # Creates an entry in the dictionary for each header
        for header in column_headers:

            dictionary.write("==========================\n"
                             "\t=" + header + "=\n"
                             "==========================\n\n\n\n")
            dictionary.write(str(df[str(column_headers[i])]))
            #for line in column_info[:-1]:
            #    dictionary.write(line + '\n')
            dictionary.write('\n')
            i += 1
```

Some of these imports might not be used. I just included all of them.

Comment: some of the code is included above the grey box for some reason... sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

you can directly write pandas dataframe to txt file ..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 100, size =3000), columns= ['Random Number'])


filename = 'dictionary.txt'
with open(filename,'w') as file:
    df.to_string(file)
```